# How to set a passphrase in Docker secrets?

Tags: docker, docker-secrets

I have the following code in js:

```
var options = {
   passphrase: process.env.APP_PASSPHRASE,
   secureProtocol: "TLSv1_2_method",
   key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname +'/key.pem', "utf8"),
   cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cert.pem', "utf8"),
   ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ca.pem', "utf8")
};

var https_server = https.createServer(options, server);
```

Currently we use get the passphrase from the env `APP_PASSPHRASE`. Now that our app is working with Docker, in our docker file you have to update the passphrase:

```
ENV APP_PASSPHRASE=<INSERT PASSPHRASE HERE>
```

I read that Docker supports private information using secrets. I read the docs but I could not figure out what would be the way to add support to the passphrase using the Docker secrets. Would be glad if someone could explain how should I add a secret for that passphrase.

Answer (score 1):

Secrets are only available with Docker Swarm

To create a secret:

```
printf <secret> | docker secret create <secret> -
```

To use a secret, it will be available in the container in the file `/run/secrets/<secret>` :

```
docker service  create --name <name> --secret <secret> <image>
```

Comment: How do I use it in the Dockerfile?

Comment: The secret is available inside the container in /run/secrets/<secret> not during the build (not in the Dockerfile).

Comment: So how should I get the secret? Should I get inside the js code? I don't think the app should know that it's being running on Docker.

Comment: Yes, you should get inside js code with passphrase: fs.readFileSync(<path>). The application doesn't know it is in docker, it just read a file on the filesystem same as you do for the certificates. I personnaly used secrets to pass the certificates into my application.

Comment: But the path is of a path to Docker's secret so it does know that it runs docker. I want to be able to still run the app without docker. So it sounds I would have to add an `if-else` statement to check somehow that I'm in docker. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: In the entrypoint of the dockerfile, you can load the secret in your environment variable then start your application. ENTRYPOINT sh -c command1 && command2 then you don't change your code